# api hmac signature in request header doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, hmac

I'm trying to use ICOBench API to access ICO data. According to their [documentation](https://icobench.com/developers) it is necessary to sign every request together with json parameters using hmac sha384.

When I don't use any parameters, the signature works as I'm only hashing the private key. But when I try hashing parameters with the key I get an `invalid signature error`

Code that partially works. Returns data from api endpoint with no parameters:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'X-ICObench-Key': PUB_KEY
           }

sig = hmac.new(PR_KEY,digestmod=hashlib.sha384).digest()

headers.update({'X-ICObench-Sig': base64.b64encode(sig)}

response = requests.request('POST', 'https://icobench.com/api/v1/icos/all', headers=headers)
```

If i try using parameters at the end of the url:

```
params = {'page':3}

response = requests.request('POST', 'https://icobench.com/api/v1/icos/all', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Returns page 0 as if no parameters we re used.

Code that doesn't work at all. `invalid signature error`. Here I use `PR_KEY` to hash json data, same way as in [this ICObench js example](https://github.com/ICObench/data-api/blob/master/ICObenchAPI.js) :

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'X-ICObench-Key': PUB_KEY
           }

params = {'page':3}

sig = hmac.new(PR_KEY, json.dumps(params), digestmod=hashlib.sha384).digest()

headers.update({'X-ICObench-Sig': base64.b64encode(sig)}

response = requests.request('POST', 'https://icobench.com/api/v1/icos/all', headers=headers)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: HTTP POST normally sends data in the _body_ aka 'content' _not_ added to the URL (as GET and HEAD do), and the 'Auth and examples' subpage(?) at the page you link shows this: it has curl with POSTFIELDS which sends body, and content-length and content-type are used which only apply to body and not URL. For python requests this is data= or json= not params= (you already have content-type correct, and content-length is probably automatic).

Comment: I changed the params= to json= and it worked! wow I didnt even know about the json kwarg. im still quite new to python. Thanks a lot!
edit: doesnt work in data= though